# Unwanted partition after partman-auto configuration

Tags: debian, partition, preseed, packer

I have an issue while i'm trying to automate the creation for my debian VM template.
I tried to create a specific disk partitioning with lvm, everything goes on correctly.
But after boot, I see that I have multiple unwanted partition on my machine.

```
# Disk Partitioning
# Use LVM, and wipe out anything that already exists
d-i partman-auto/disk string /dev/sda /dev/sdb /dev/sdc
# The presently available methods are: "regular", "lvm" and "crypto"
d-i partman-auto/method string lvm
d-i partman-auto-lvm/guided_size string 100%


d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string                                         \
    custom ::                                                                 \

            100 300 500 ext3                                                \
                    $primary{ }                                               \
                    $bootable{ }                                              \
                    method{ format }                                          \
                    format{ }                                                 \
                    use_filesystem{ }                                         \
                    filesystem{ ext3 }                                        \
                    mountpoint{ /boot } .                                     \
            100 10000 1000000000 lvm                                           \
                    $primary{ }                                               \
                    $defaultignore{ }                                         \
                    method{ lvm }                                             \
                    device{ /dev/sdb }                                        \
                    vg_name{ rootvg } .                                       \
            100 3000 5000 ext4                                             \
                    $lvmok{ }                                                 \
                    in_vg{ rootvg }                                           \
                    lv_name{ root }                                           \
                    method{ format }                                          \
                    format{ }                                                 \
                    use_filesystem{ }                                         \
                    filesystem{ ext4 }                                        \
                    mountpoint{ / } .                                         \
            1024 1024 100% linux-swap                                         \
                    $lvmok{ }                                                 \
                    in_vg{ rootvg }                                           \
                    lv_name{ swap }                                           \
                    method{ swap }                                            \
                    format{ } .                                               \
            1 512 1024 ext4                                               \
                    $lvmok{ }                                                 \
                    in_vg{ rootvg }                                           \
                    lv_name{ tmp }                                            \
                    method{ format }                                          \
                    format{ }                                                 \
                    use_filesystem{ }                                         \
                    filesystem{ ext4 }                                        \
                    mountpoint{ /tmp } .                                      \
            1 512 1024 ext4                                                  \
                    $lvmok{ }                                                 \
                    in_vg{ rootvg }                                           \
                    lv_name{ var }                                            \
                    method{ format }                                          \
                    format{ }                                                 \
                    use_filesystem{ }                                         \
                    filesystem{ ext4 }                                        \
                    mountpoint{ /var } .                                      \
            1 256 512 ext4                                                 \
                    $lvmok{ }                                                 \
                    in_vg{ rootvg }                                           \
                    lv_name{ home }                                           \
                    method{ format }                                          \
                    format{ }                                                 \
                    use_filesystem{ }                                         \
                    filesystem{ ext4 }                                        \
                    mountpoint{ /home } .                                     \
            100 5000 1000000000 lvm                                           \
                    $primary{ }                                               \
                    $defaultignore{ }                                         \
                    method{ lvm }                                             \
                    device{ /dev/sdc }                                        \
                    vg_name{ datavg } .                                       \
            2048 1 2048 ext4                                               \
                    $lvmok{ }                                                 \
                    in_vg{ datavg }                                           \
                    lv_name{ opt }                                            \
                    method{ format }                                          \
                    format{ }                                                 \
                    use_filesystem{ }                                         \
                    filesystem{ ext4 }                                        \
                    mountpoint{ /opt } .                                      \

d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select custom

# If one of the disks that are going to be automatically partitioned
# contains an old LVM configuration, the user will normally receive a
# warning. This can be preseeded away...
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/purge_lvm_from_device boolean true

# This makes partman automatically partition without confirmation.
d-i partman/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition select finish
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true

# Mount Partitions by UUID
d-i partman/mount_style select uuid
```

This result with something like this :

```
~$ lsblk
NAME            MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda               8:0    0  400M  0 disk
├─sda1            8:1    0  132M  0 part /boot
├─sda2            8:2    0    1K  0 part
└─sda5            8:5    0  265M  0 part
sdb               8:16   0  5,9G  0 disk
└─sdb1            8:17   0  5,9G  0 part
  ├─rootvg-root 254:0    0  3,5G  0 lvm  /
  ├─rootvg-swap 254:1    0  976M  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  ├─rootvg-tmp  254:3    0  596M  0 lvm  /tmp
  ├─rootvg-var  254:4    0  596M  0 lvm  /var
  └─rootvg-home 254:5    0  296M  0 lvm  /home
sdc               8:32   0  2,2G  0 disk
└─sdc1            8:33   0  2,2G  0 part
  └─datavg-opt  254:2    0  1,9G  0 lvm  /opt
sr0              11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
```

So my question are : Why are **sda2, sda5, sdb1 and sdc1** partition are created and how to avoid it ?

Thank you.

Comment: May be you need cleanup sda partition table in your recipe? sdc datavg in your recipe so its created Did you read recipe?